# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. - DocuSign EnvelopesApi calls ONLY to PROD environment

Tags: docusignapi

I have migrating our Apis to use Docusign OAuth authentication flow. While testing I found that the code works perfectly fine when I point to Docusign Demo environment. However when I point to docusign Prod environment I get the following error.

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

There inner exception is actually null.

The docusign Auth call is fine and we get the accountId as expected. However the EnvelopesApi calls are failing. I do have a ticket open with Docusign but wanted to see if any one can help.

Our Api is deployed as a Windows Service and is in dotnet core 5.0. However I have tested this by deploying the Api to an IIS website with ssl binding and I can repro the same exception.

Auth Flow - OAuth JwtFlow

API BasePath as - "https : //docusign.net/restapi" (space added on purpose)

OAuth Base Path as - "account.docusign.com"

Below code get the accountId and sets the AccessToken. This is successful.

```
    var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docuSignKey);
        try
        {
            _tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(docusignConfig.IntegratorKey, docusignConfig.UserIdGuid,
                                        docusignConfig.OAuthBasePath, privateKeyBytes, docusignConfig.TokenExpiryInHours);
            var userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(_tokenInfo?.access_token);
            var account = userInfo?.Accounts
                .FirstOrDefault(la => la.IsDefault.ToLowerInvariant() == true.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                ?? userInfo?.Accounts.First();
            SetApiClientConfiguration(docusignConfig); 
            return account?.AccountId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ESignLogger.Error($"{GetType().Name}.{nameof(AuthorizeAndGetAccountId)}. Error in getting account details. " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
```

Below code is the envelopesApi call which **fails**.

```
    var recipientResponse = await _envelopesApi.ListRecipientsAsync(accountId, envelopeId);
```

Comment: What is the baseURI you're using in production? how do you determine this? can you share your code?

Comment: More questions: are you using the C# SDK/Nuget? can you test the same code from a developer machine directly and not from the Windows Service?

Comment: I use the API BasePath as  - "https : //docusign.net/restapi" (Added space on purpose for this post), OAuth Base Path as - "account.docusign.com" and I use the Docusign SDK (5.7.0) to connect. For demo environment I just change the demo Urls and UserId, integrator key which I am not sharing here.

Comment: @InbarGazit - Added code in the original post. Please note this flow works in demo environment. I have that tested for multiple accounts in demo.

Comment: so note docusign.net without anything would go to www.docusign.net but your account may be in some other URL, which is why best practice is to first find the baseURI from the call to getUserInfo

Comment: However, your error could also be a cert related issue, which is why I asked about running from a different box/machine. You may need to download a cert in your server, I'm not sure about this.

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates

Comment: Do you use a proxy? firewall? something like that?

Comment: I think you just gave me the biggest hint that DocuSign did not give me even though I have an active ticket. I think I was missing WWW in the base URL.  I am going to verify this in other environment as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs for eSignature REST API calls for the DocuSign production environments can be different for different customers based on where their account is provisioned.
The default URL (https://www.docusign.net/restapi) can be used in some cases.
However, the best practice is to call the [User Info endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) for the particular user (it's by account, but a user can be a member of more than one account) and for each account that user is a member of, you'll get back a baseURI that can be different than the default I just posted above.

If this wasn't your issue, it may also be that you need to download one of the certificates to your server. You can find all of DocuSign SSL certificates in [this page](https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to check:

1. OAuth step to obtain an access_token. You're using the JWT grant flow. If it returns an access token from account.docusign.com then you've succeeded. Note that your client ID (integration key) needs to pass go-live before it can be used with account.docusign.com
2. Next use the access token with the right base url for the eSig API. You can determine the right base url by using the [/oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API. Or if your application is just for your own company, you can just look up your DocuSign account's base URL from the API & Keys page of the eSignature Settings (admin) tool.